# How to 'push' the links to the bottom of the card in bootstrap 3 and flexbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I got this grid of cards in bootstrap 3.3.7, as you can see, the height of all grids is the same, but, when an image is smaller than the other then it pulls the links up.

Here's the image:
[image]

**How can i "push" the text to always be at the bottom, no matter what image size i upload?**

here's the flexbox code i use for equal cards:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
flex:1 1 auto;
 }
}

.panel {
width: 100%;
}
```

the css for the cards:

```
 .card .card-image {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card .card-image img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.card {
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 4px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.card .card-content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.card .card-content .card-title, .card-reveal .card-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.card .card-action {
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
}

.card .card-action a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.card .card-action a:hover {
  color: #ffd8a6;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card .card-reveal {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*top: 0;*/
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.card .card-reveal p {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);
  margin: 20px;
}
```

and here is the html code:

```
<div class="row equal">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let pet of pets">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="./uploads/user/{{ pet.owner }}/{{ pet.imageURL}}">
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">{{ pet.name }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a [routerLink]="['../pet', pet._id]"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Επεξεργασία</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['../pet', pet._id]" style="color:red;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Διαγραφή</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to wrap your `.row` inside a `.container`, otherwise it would cause overflow in x-direction.

Second use flex on `.equal > div[class*='col-'] .card` instead of `.equal > div[class*='col-']` and also give this `.card` `height:100%;` and `flex-direction:column;`. Then use `flex-frow:1;` on your `.card-content` so it would take the rest of the height in the `.card` and push the button to the bottom.

**EDIT :** Since you want to push `.card-content` to the bottom too. Add an empty div right before the `.card-content` with some class like `.togrow` and use `flex-grow:1;` on this instead of `.card-content`

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] .card{
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
}
.equal > div[class*='col-'] .card{
  flex-direction:column;
}
}

.panel {
width: 100%;
}

the css for the cards:

 .card .card-image {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card .card-image img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}

.card {
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 4px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.card .card-content {
  padding: 10px;
}
.card .togrow{
  flex-grow:1;
}

.card .card-content .card-title, .card-reveal .card-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.card .card-action {
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
}

.card .card-action a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.card .card-action a:hover {
  color: #ffd8a6;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card .card-reveal {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*top: 0;*/
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.card .card-reveal p {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row equal">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let pet of pets">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="togrow"> 
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">{{ pet.name }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a [routerLink]="['../pet', pet._id]"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Επεξεργασία</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['../pet', pet._id]" style="color:red;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Διαγραφή</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let pet of pets">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://images.financialexpress.com/2015/12/Lead-image.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="togrow"> 
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">{{ pet.name }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a [routerLink]="['../pet', pet._id]"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Επεξεργασία</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['../pet', pet._id]" style="color:red;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Διαγραφή</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let pet of pets">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Eiffel_Tower_Vertical.JPG">
      </div>
      <div class="togrow"> 
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">{{ pet.name }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a [routerLink]="['../pet', pet._id]"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Επεξεργασία</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['../pet', pet._id]" style="color:red;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Διαγραφή</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: excellent! how i can push the {{pet.name}} too at the bottom?  Thank you very much!